Unable to figure out the gap in my solution against "LeetCode 334. Increasing Triplet Subsequence"
LeetCode 334 Question:
Given an integer array nums, return true if there exists a triple of indices (i, j, k) such that i < j < k and nums[i] < nums[j] < nums[k]. If no such indices exists, return false.
Example 1:
Input: nums = [1,2,3,4,5]
Output: true
Explanation: Any triplet where i < j < k is valid.
Example 2:
Input: nums = [5,4,3,2,1]
Output: false
Explanation: No triplet exists.
Example 3:
Input: nums = [2,1,5,0,4,6]
Output: true
Explanation: The triplet (3, 4, 5) is valid because nums[3] == 0 < nums[4] == 4 < nums[5] == 6.
So I solved the above question as below Approach, it worked for all testcases except for input
"nums =[20,100,10,12,5,13]". my expectation is that it should work for this input as well.
I am unable to figure it out why its not working for this input. Can someone explain!
Code I wrote:
class Solution {
    public boolean increasingTriplet(int[] nums) {
        if(nums.length<3){
            return false;
        }
        for(int i=0;i<nums.length-2;i++){
            if(i==nums.length-2){
                return false;
            }
            else if(nums[i]<nums[i+1]&&nums[i+1]<nums[i+2]){
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}


Your code assumes that i, j and k are exactly 1 apart each. But in the sample you gave they would be 2, 3 and 5 respectively.

The question asks for any triplet not any consecutive triplet (as also commented):
public class Solution {
    public boolean increasingTriplet(int[] nums) {
        int one = Integer.MAX_VALUE, two = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        for (int num : nums) {
            if (num <= one)
                one = num;
            else if (num <= two)
                two = num;
            else
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Solution solution = new Solution();

        int[] nums = { 20, 100, 10, 12, 5, 13 };
        System.out.println(solution.increasingTriplet(nums));

    }
}


which outputs:
true

